is there any method to work a middleware that can update a app.locals variable dynamically
I am in the middle of an e-commerce project using Node. The problem is that I want to show the count of notifications that an admin has received on the admin side. The notifications are the orders that user's requested to return. Because of that I want to show the notification count on all admin pages. To solve it I made a middleware to run whenever the admin changes a page.
When the page loads I given a middleware on admin route page as following:
admin_route.all(async (req, res, next) => {
  // console.log('Middleware executed');
  try {
    const adminNotificationsCount = await Notifications.find({ 
      matter: 'returnOrderRequest' 
    }).countDocuments();
    res.locals.adminNotifications = adminNotificationsCount;
    next();
  } catch (error) {     
    console.log(error.message);
  };
});

However the middleware is not working. Because of that there has nothing in the global variable.
Is there any problem with this or any other method to implement?

But the middleware is not working so, you mean it's not doing what you expect or it's not even being called? you have a console.log('Middleware executed'); but it seems to be commented out (can't tell, your code is not formatted at all)

it is not even calling that middleware

how do you know? did you uncomment console.log('Middleware executed'); and watch the console?

Yes, I already watched.  I also given a console before and after that middleware function, those two were working but not that inside one.

I got it. This is an utter unworldly question when i got the answer.
The problem is that the lack of knowledge of mine how the app.all() works. When i give app.use() everything has worked perfectly and i can access the global variable(app.locals) on the ejs directly.
